# Extracting characters and integer from a string

Tags: java, string

I have this String p="V755D888B154" and i want to split it to have this form

- V
- 755
- D
- 888
- B
- 154

How can i do it ? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you always going to have three letters and three numbers between 100 and 999? Regex may be one way to go. Java substring may be another if the character positions are fixed.

Comment: The letters are fixed but the numbers aren't , and yes they are between 100 and 999

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Example:

```
String[] numbers = p.split("[a-zA-Z]+");
String[] letters = p.split("[0-9]+");
```

`numbers` or `letters` can have empty string, but you can check it manually.

Comment: That really worked it separated the string and the numbers like i've wanted . thank you and also so many thanks and respect for the other answers ! i have so much respect for what you do here trying helps us , we the newbies :)

Answer (score 0):

If your string contains only numbers and strings this snippets workes

```
    String string = "V755D888B154";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+|\\D+");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(string);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        Integer i = null;
        String s = null;
        try {
            i = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            s = matcher.group();
        }
        if (i != null) System.out.println("NUMBER: " + i);
        if (s != null) System.out.println("STRING: " + s);
    }
```

main fail is checking if given String (matcher.group()) consist Integer or not

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you say the letters are fixed, so you if you're just trying to pull out the numbers you could always do something like this. I'll leave it up to you if you think this is a kluge.

```
String p="V755D888B154";

Integer vPart = Integer.valueOf(p.substring(1,4));
Integer dPart = Integer.valueOf(p.substring(5,8));
Integer bPart = Integer.valueOf(p.substring(9,12));

System.out.println(bPart);
```